# How to install gcc..the install wizard doesn't response?

Tags: eclipse, gcc, ide

I'm trying to install Eclipse for C/C++ developers on windows 7 for C programming, and it's essential to install compiler gcc, I downloaded many versions form equation.com and from other websites, but when running the .exe file it comes to the end of the installation and the wizard halt, not responding, I waited for about 10 minutes but still no responding, don't know what to do?

Comment: I dont know exactly what you are trying to install but i previously had success with the mingw compiler on windows using Eclipse C/C++ plugin: www.mingw.org/

Comment: @TheDMerged would you please type the link of the version you used?
cause as I told I downloaded many versions from equation.com and tried to install them  but it didn't work

Comment: It was years ago but I think I followed this tutorial: http://max.berger.name/howto/cdt/ar01s03.jsp#wincompiler.
This is probably the mingw version you want http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/latest/download?source=files. But I think you need a bit of reading to get it working:(

Comment: @TheDMerged when I typed gcc --version in the command line it gave me gcc 4.7.0 I think this means that I have gcc installed on my computer right? but when I run a code on elips errors appear like "arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc" not found in PATH ?

Answer (score 0):

Okey, you have GCC installed according to your comment. Then all you need to do is to set path in eclipse. Its done under window-> preferences-> your plugin -> compiler something -> edit the path to your compiler

I dont have the plugin installed so I cant point it out with better precision:(

Hope you can find it

Comment: No, I don't get it honestly

Comment: Do you have eclipse and the plugin installed?

Comment: OK, Now I solved the problem, installing MinGW again, thank you